# Is there a way to sync iPhones without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I really dislike iTunes and would like to use something else to sync.  I spent some time looking a couple years ago (for my iPod) and couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-sync-music-to-your-iphone-without-itunes/) :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) its really awesome, you can just copy stuff to the
iphone just like iTunes. its basicaly more for storage videos, system files, music
and not for installing apps I believe, but tis really awesome that you don't have to
have everything double on your comp and on the iphone!!! (like in itunes)