# Motorola v3i iTunes installtion

Tags: itunes, mobile-phone

I am using Motorazr v3i since last 2 years. It very much satisfy my needs. But only one problem that I am facing is that the iTunes song copy from my PC to Phone. If I go somewhere I find it difficult to install iTunes everytime on those machines to just copy songs. Is there any software which can simple connects to my phone and copy songs without iTunes ?

Comment: I'm sure this a duplicate - can't find it at the moment though.

Comment: Ah - found one - http://superuser.com/questions/3065/is-there-a-way-to-sync-iphones-without-itunes

Comment: those are all for iPhones , will not work in my v3i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [MotoTunes](http://www.e398mod.com/content/view/92/28/) . It satisfies my actual needs